# Achieve filter response similar to Matlab filtfilt in realtime?

Tags: matlab, filter, filtering, signal-processing

I have face a problem for last few months where solution to it seems like a dream to me! :D

Work i followed...
Initially i high pass a certain signal to remove dc shift of it using filtfilt function of matlab. The results were as intended.

But when i implement the same high pass filter in real time with matlab fdatool (butterworth filter with order2) filter response changes dramatically.

Seems like filtfilt function implementation is perfect possibly due to zero phase.
It's also important to notice phase plays a important in my filtering process?

Can anyone help me to design a real time filter which gives matlab filtfilt performance?

Comment: No way. If you have a crystal ball to look a bit forward in the future, then you can do what filtfilt does, otherwise forget about it.

Comment: My recommendation would be to compare the frequency content of the DC signals you're trying to remove to what kind of delays from realtime are acceptable to you.  Also consider the nature of your DC signal.  Does it have a distinct frequency that you might be able to identify the phase of for an acceptably long window?  Is it a stable DC offset that you could simply remove by filtering a previously seen response window?

Comment: @aka.nice: Well, does "realtime" include reading in small chunks at a time and processing them?

Comment: @endolith Alas, what is the phase shift of this transfer function e^(-T s) (s = Laplace variable)? In this sense, the hope to reduce phase shift by introducing such small delays is void, or I don't understand what a real time requirement means (like has to be used in some sort of a feedback loop). Beside, beware of high frequency noise which could be introduced by using filtfilt on a sliding window, I encourage you to try it.

Comment: @aka.nice: Well, *any* system will have some delay.  How much delay can you have while still calling something realtime?

Comment: @endolith sure, it's not a problem of having zero delay, it's a problem of not increasing the overall delay. Is pure delay+filtfilt better than simple filt with this respect?

Comment: real time zero phase filtering is possible in digital world, Not be accurate as filtfilt but to an extend of accuracy over 80%... Wait for a publication in near future! :) :) :)